# User Input , How can we do it?

Tags: prolog

How can we get something from user in prolog : 
for example :

```
animal(dog).
animal(cat).
write('please type animal name:'),nl.
/* How to read from user and store it to X 
and then check that user has typed animal name ?*/
?-animal(X).
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use `read` for that. For example you could write `read(X), animal(X).` into the prolog interpreter or write this into a script file:

```
:- read(X), animal(X).
```

If you then enter a valid animal name into the prompt, it will be bound to X. If you enter an invalid name, it won't.

Or you could define a procedure like this:

```
read_animal(X) :-
  write('please type animal name:'),
  nl,
  read(X),
  animal(X).
```

And then call it in the in the interpreter like `read_animal(X).`.

Note that the input needs to be terminated by a `.`.

Comment: animal(dog).
animal(cat).
animal(cow).
write('Please enter an animal name:'),nl.
Read(X).
animal(X).

Comment: @Parkhid: It's `read`, not `Read`. Also note that you need to terminate the input with a `.`. I edited my answer to clarify. It definitely does work.

Answer (score 1):

```
Animal('X').

Input:- write("enter your name"),nl, 
        read(X), nl, 
        write(X).
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading values

```
%                   name  id
 stud_name('ankit',01).
 stud_name('varun ',02).

Read_stud:-
  write("write name to know Id of student "),nl, 
  Read(Input),nl, 
  stud_name(Input,Output),nl,
  write(Output).
```

Comment: Hello ankit! Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you are wondering why your answers were downvoted, here are some hints: (a) This question is six years old. (b) There is already an accepted answer with many upvotes, and your answers did not add anything new. (c) Please explain the code you post in full sentences. (d) Please format your code nicely and use correct code formatting (https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).